# AngularDart or PolymerDart 2015

Tags: dart

I have been some time away from Dart. What happened to AngularDart and PolymerDart?

What is the way to go 2015?

Answer (score 3):

Angular has released 1.0 but left it quite unmainained and development now focuses on Angular 2.0 which is written in AtScript and transpiled to Dart and JS. An early alpha of Angular 2.0 for Dart is available at pub.dartlang.org.

Polymer has evolved slowly the recent year. Most effort went into core- and paper-elements. Recently Polymer 0.8 (current 0.5.x) was announced and will bring some breaking changes. The architecture is changed to allow to choose between different levels of support (and with it the library size you add to your app) and some breaking changes how attributes and properties are defined and used.
A Polymer.js 0.8 release is expected during this month, availability for Dart will take a few weeks longer I guess.

Comment: Actually, I'm watching ng-conf right now, and AtScript is out for Angular 2. It's all gonna be TypeScript from now on. TypeScript has incorporated annotations.

Comment: this angular/polymer confusion does not help dart. There should be 1 single standard defaul UI to start with.

Comment: Some people like/don't like Angular, some like/don't like Polymer, others like/don't like react. One size fits all will never happen.